# Tcl pathInFilesystemProc get current filesystem

Tags: c, tcl, vfs

When creating a vfs using the tcl api how do you get the current filesystem in `Tcl_Filesystem.pathInFilesystemProc`

My code looks something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    FILE* dbFile;
    /*...*/

} FSBackend;

void createFS(const char* dbFile)
{

    FSBackend* fsback = (FSBackend*)malloc(sizeof(FSBackend));
    initDb(fsback,dbFile);

    Tcl_Filesystem tfs;

    tfs.typeName="Db Fs";
    tfs.structureLength = sizeof(Tcl_Filesystem);
    tfs.version = TCL_FILESYSTEM_VERSION_1;
    tfs.pathInFilesystemProc = inFsProc;

    /*...*/

    Tcl_FSRegister((void*),tfs);
}

int inFsProc(Tcl_Obj* pathPtr,ClientData* cd)
{
    /* How do I get my FSBackend struct here */
    FSBackend* bk = /* ? */

    int len;

    const char* searchPath = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(pathPtr,&len);

    char* foundPath = findFileInDb(searchPath,bk);

    if (foundPath == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    cd = buildInternalRep(foundPath,bk);
    return TCL_OK;
}

/**
 ...
*/

int main()
{
    createFS("db1.db");
    createFS("db2.db");
}
```

How do I, in `inFsProc` get back the struct I passed into `Tcl_FSRegister`?

The `Tcl_FSData` function says it can get it but I would then need to get a Tcl_Filesystem pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird one. The `clientData` handle there is *not* used to specify a mount point, but rather a separate capability of the filesystem *type*. Tcl's internal use of `Tcl_FSRegister` doesn't use it at all. The code which is as close as anything to a canonical use of it is the **tclvfs** package.

[https://github.com/tcl-mirror/tclvfs/blob/master/generic/vfs.c#L385](https://github.com/tcl-mirror/tclvfs/blob/d37fe33223289cc9509143891b0909dd480d6635/generic/vfs.c#L385) shows us the use:

```c
static void 
Vfs_RegisterWithInterp(interp)
    Tcl_Interp *interp;
{
    ClientData vfsAlreadyRegistered;
    /* 
     * We need to know if the interpreter is deleted, so we can
     * remove all interp-specific mounts.
     */
    Tcl_SetAssocData(interp, "vfs::inUse", (Tcl_InterpDeleteProc*) 
             Vfs_UnregisterWithInterp, (ClientData) 1);
    /* 
     * Perform one-off registering of our filesystem if that
     * has not happened before.
     */
    vfsAlreadyRegistered = Tcl_FSData(&vfsFilesystem);
    if (vfsAlreadyRegistered == NULL) {
        Tcl_FSRegister((ClientData)1, &vfsFilesystem);
        Tcl_CreateExitHandler(VfsExitProc, (ClientData)NULL);
        Tcl_CreateThreadExitHandler(VfsThreadExitProc, NULL);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `clientData` there is really just being used as a marker so the code knows whether to do one-time initialisation.

To discover what the mount mapping is, you'll need to keep internal structures. You're strongly recommended to make the `Tcl_Filesystem` structure instance itself be global (or rather `static` at file scope) in your code.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the call to `Tcl_CreateThreadExitHandler` is correct, BTW. A thread exit handler belongs on every thread that has resources that need to be deleted when a thread goes away, not just the first thread. Something smells wrong with where it is being placed. The thread-specific data probably should be used for that purpose rather than the global tracking that `Tcl_FSData` handles.

Comment: Also, that C file is basically the whole of the code part of the implementation of tclvfs; everything else in the project relates to build, documentation, and testing.

Comment: The canonical location for the file is https://core.tcl-lang.org/tclvfs/file?name=generic/vfs.c&ci=tip but that doesn't include any syntax highlighting so it's harder to read.